# How to implement multiple channels in wifi module of ns3

Tags: ns-3

My objective is to create multiple link/channels to connect with different wifi nodes surrounding it. In the example "wifi-simple-adhoc-grid", only one channel per wifi node is created. How can I extend this to multiple channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

- install multiple NetDevices. This configuration is known as
  multi-radio scenario.
- have a look at the WAVE module that has
  support for multi-channel, implementing the IEEE 1609.4. This
  installs single radio with multi-channel.

Comment: I have used multiple NetDevices and the configuration worked to my expectation. To avoid interference, I modified the ranges of the wireless signal strength so that only the nodes under consideration can forward packets.