# How can i create two wireless channels c1 and c2 on the same node in NS-3

Tags: ns-3

The problem that I want to set multiple interfaces on the same nod in NS-3. As I know, I can use this command NetDevice. However, I do not the way that I can set more than one channel to same node.

My Regards.

Comment: Do you want to implement multiple channels (on a single node) on one Wi-Fi physical layer? I will assume wifi because you have not mentioned the technology.

Comment: Possible duplication of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949231/how-to-implement-multiple-channels-in-wifi-module-of-ns3]

Comment: Here is the solution with code. [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ns-3-users/8_CqgJgxehI]

Comment: @a4arshad, thanks for your answer, I will try to check all thesis link. Maybe I can find the answer. Yes, wi-fi.